# Select query within a particluar radius in postGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am new to this postGIS. My requirement is  to retrieve data with the particular radius.IN my database i have the_geom(POINT).Now i have a query which will retrieve data within 2 DEGREE from the given point.

My query is:

```
select level4,level3
        from xxxxxxx
        where st_distance(the_geom,'SRID=4326;POINT(79.932018 12.513343)') < 2;
```

But i need to retrieve the points within particular kms or meters.. Help me  to solve this.Thanks in advance..

Whether i have to have the column "Geography".I think now i  have geometry column??

Comment: whats the _problem with above query_ ?

Comment: @Vijaykumar Hadalgi  Nothing problem with the above query..Actually in that query <2 means less than 2 degree from my point.But i want less than 2 kms or 2 meters query..Y because degree is not easy to understand,but if it is in meter or kms its easy..SO i need query to retrieve with 2 kms from my given point..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the geography data type. Then you can use the `ST_DWithin` function:

```
boolean ST_DWithin(geography gg1, 
                   geography gg2, 
                   double precision distance_meters);
```

You can use this query:

```
select level4,level3
    from xxxxxxx
    where st_dWithin(the_geom,'SRID=4326;POINT(79.932018 12.513343)', 2000);
```

See also [this page in the postGIS manual](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html).

Comment: I found the following query: "select level4,level3
from TN_Village
where ST_Distance_Sphere(the_geom,'SRID=4326;POINT(79.932018 12.513343)')<1000;" ..